# Non-web Javascript frameworks

Tags: javascript, frameworks, desktop

Are there any good JavaScript frameworks out there which primary audience is not web programming? Especially frameworks/libraries which improves the object orientation?
The framework should be usable within an desktop application embedding a JavaScript engine (such as Spidermonkey or JavaScriptCore), so no external dependency are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) can be used (and is used) in non-browser environments (e.g., Rhino, Jaxer, SpiderMonkey). It can be easily adapted for other environments too — all DOM-related functions are separated from functions dealing with global language features.

[dojo.declare()](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojo/1.2/dojo.declare) ([more docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/declare)) comes in the Dojo Base (as soon as you load dojo.js) and implements full-blown OOP with single- and multiple- inheritance, automatic constructor chaining, and super-calls. In fact it is the cornerstone of many Dojo facilities.

Of course there are more low-level facilities like [dojo.mixin()](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojo/1.2/dojo.mixin) to mix objects together and [dojo.extend()](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojo/1.2/dojo.extend) to extend a prototype dynamically.

More language-related features can be found in [dojox.lang](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/lang/). Following parts of it are thoroughly explained and documented: [functional](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/jan/12/functional-fun-javascript-dojo/), [AOP](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/may/18/aop-aspect-javascript-dojo/), [recursion combinators](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/jun/30/using-recursion-combinators-javascript/).

Dojo comes with other batteries included from string-related algorithms to the date processing. If you are interested in those [you can discover them yourself](http://docs.dojocampus.org/), or contact [the Dojo community](http://dojotoolkit.org/community/).

Answer (score 4):

As far as "improving object orientation" goes, Javascript is already great.  You just need to get used to thinking in prototypes instead of classes.

After reading Douglas Crawford's [great page on prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) I really started to enjoy working with javascript.  (He also has [a page on class inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html) if you must use classes.)

**Edit:**  If by asking for a *framework* you also mean, *helpful libraries that don't use the DOM*, you might be interested in [Functional Javascript](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/).

Comment: Well, Javascript as a language is rather chatty, at least for me  who is coming from a python background. A framework to reduce the amount of typing needed would be great.

Comment: I'm a Python user too, so I know what you mean :)

For me the biggest pain in javascript is the for loop, but the Functional library mentioned in my edit *greatly* helps that.

Answer (score 0):

[Objective-J](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/objective-j-tutorial.php)(avascript) is one. Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. I'm just looking for a framework, not another language.

Answer (score 0):

The most widely known one is XULRunner from Mozilla. This is framework that FireFox and Thunderbird are built on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner

Although not strictly javascript only, it incorporates a host of technologies closely tied to web for the purposes of building desktop applications.

Comment: I'm actually using the javascript engine (spidermonkey) from xulrunner, but I don want the rest of the technoligies related to firefox such as gecko,xpcom,xpconnect etc. I have my own replacement for those.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Adobe Air? It allows you to use JavaScript/AJAX to write Desktop applications.

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

Comment: Not interested in web stuff. Besides, is air really free software?

Comment: You never mentioned 'free' Johan.